# Looking for Parish Boundaries Datasets for QLD Austraila

Tags: shapefile, data, file-geodatabase, australia, boundaries

Every so often, I am asked for a parish boundary dataset. I can never find them as I am of the belief that they are no longer used. Has any one had any experience with parish boundaries in Australia (related to the state of Queensland) that could shed some light on the subject. I do know that the current [Cadastral (DCDB)](http://qldspatial.information.qld.gov.au/catalogue/custom/detail.page?fid=%7B4091CAF1-50E6-4BC3-B3D4-229AA318231A%7D) does contain the parish attributes (see [answer below](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155349)), but  I guess what I am really looking for is a current parish boundaries dataset (if it exist) that I could use to check against Cadastre (DCDB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get this from the [Queensland Spatial Catalogue (QSpatial)](http://qldspatial.information.qld.gov.au/catalogue/custom/index.page).

The Cadastral (DCDB) datasets, at least for each Local Government Area (LGA), have a field for PARISH, which can be used to dissolve them out.

[image]

The only catch is that there will be gaps in the dissolved parishes that represent the roads.

I think that it is quite likely that the Queensland Government has this dataset as polygons too.  To find out if that is the case I recommend that you use QSpatial's [Contact Us](https://www.qld.gov.au/contact-us/) button which says (with my **bolding**):

> Please use this form to submit general enquiries, or send comments and
>   suggestions for the Queensland Government website.
>
> In particular, we are interested to know which information you found
>   most useful and why, and **what other type of information you would
>   like** to see featured on the site.

Comment: I had thought of this and should have mentioned it in my question. I just want to be sure that the cadastral (DCDB) boundaries matches that of the parish boundaries. I have seen that some of the road and water corridors encroach in to other parish boundaries so I wasn't sure if this was correct or an error in the data.

Comment: I think you are right and I will contact QSpatial about the matter.

Answer (score 3):

County and Parish are no longer part of legal descriptions of land. The do still feature on survey plans and property contracts, but more so for historical reference purposes. Parish boundaries were drawn on Parish Maps which were fairly small scale and paid little (if any) attention to features outside the boundary. [Here's a sample](https://geospatial.information.qld.gov.au/arcgisoutput/cadscans/cad-map-40chain-parish-drayton-1971.jpg).  You can find others [here](https://www.dnrm.qld.gov.au/qld/environment/land/place-names/search) by filtering by parish.
I can also tell you that parish boundaries cannot be assumed to follow property boundaries in all instances, for example if several lots are amalgamated and parish boundary is on a boundary internal to the new lot, the parish boundary in the DCDB will remain in the position of the old lot boundary (or should if the updater is doing it correctly!).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I found this particularly interesting _"parish boundaries cannot be assumed to follow property boundaries in all instances"_

Comment: Back "in the day" each property would have been within a single Parish, but as @PolyGeo discovered, Parish/County boundaries are purely historical and there's been talk for quite some time to remove those attributes from the DCDB. Hopefully someone will make the call one day...

Comment: Some news in this space... [Removal of parish and county](https://www.dnrm.qld.gov.au/mapping-data/removal-parish-county)

Answer (score 2):

After taking [@PolyGo's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155349/18320) suggestion, I contacted [QSpatial](http://qldspatial.information.qld.gov.au/catalogue/custom/index.page) regarding if a parish boundary dataset exists for Queensland (Australia) - this was the response:

*"Parish names and boundaries are actually historical information. 
Parish mapping and the parish information in the DCDB has not been maintained for many years. Unfortunately as the parish boundaries are historical we do not have a dataset that displays them."*

So in answer to my question, it ***appears that a parish boundary dataset no-longer exists***.

Comment: In actual fact a parish dataset never did exist. Point of truth for parish boundaries is the old parish maps which were never oficially digitised. but what were you planning to do with the parish polygons.

Comment: I just want to be sure that the cadastral (DCDB) boundaries matches that of the parish boundaries. I have seen that some of the road and water corridors encroach in to other parish boundaries (if I use the DCDB) so I wasn't sure if this was correct or an error in the data

Comment: I plan to refer to this Q&A if we ever get asked about Queensland Parish Boundaries on [genealogy.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: [Removal of parish and county](https://www.dnrm.qld.gov.au/mapping-data/removal-parish-county) from DCDB effective 30 November 2015